# How does the lombok constructor differ from the normal constructor (generally and when using the final keyword and when using the @value() keyword)

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, lombok, final

So i'm working on a project using spring
i'm trying to define a string value using the propreties.yml file
using @Value("${sthg.sthg}")
here is an image of it

```java
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GedAuthenticationServiceImpl implements GedAuthenticationService {
    @Value("${app.alfresco.alfresco_urls.alfresco_login_url}")
    private  final String authUrl;
```

and i get this error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in package.class required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

and if i use the normal constructor like this

```java
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class GedAuthenticationServiceImpl implements GedAuthenticationService {
    private  final String authUrl;

    public GedAuthenticationServiceImpl( @Value("${app.alfresco.alfresco_urls.alfresco_login_url}") String authUrl) {
        this.authUrl = authUrl;
    }
```

it works just finneee

as i said i used the normal constructor but i don't know why it wouldn't work with the other one
and i can't seem to get the difference between the too cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `@AllArgsConstructor`, you are using a **Constructor Injection** under the hood, by default when you have only ONE constructor in your Spring component class, it will use DI.

What I mean by under the hood is that *Lombok* wrote a code similar to this:

```
public YourSeviceClass(String test) {
        this.test = test;
}
```

And in your example, there no `String` bean declared in your application, so the Spring container can't inject it.

Create a separate config class that contains your login configs. Don't mix everything in your service class, it will make you code so ugly and **hard to read** in the future.

Example (Use Records if you are using Java 17):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.alfresco...ect")
public class PropertyConfig {

    private String myVariableName;
    ...
}
```

Check this for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: but also when i write the constructor with my hand it is one constructor in the class so why didn't it use DI in that case too

Comment: @firoudreda in your example you wrote `@Value` in the constructor that's why it's working. If you delete the `@Value` it will not work, like I mentioned in my response Lombok doesn't recognize instance variable annotations such as @Value

Answer (score 1):

Since `lombok` has no idea what to do with `@Value` annotation over field declaration, it does nothing and creates constructor like:

```java
    public GedAuthenticationServiceImpl(String authUrl) {
        this.authUrl = authUrl;
    }
```

which in turn causes `spring` to fail, because now `spring` has no idea what to do with that constructor. On `lombok` side that is possible ask it to copy field annotations to constructor parameters - please check [`lombok.copyableAnnotations` configuration key](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), however, I would suggest to pay attention to [@iLyas suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75779168/3426309) and start using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: Thanks man its helpful i searched after reading your comment and @iLyas's and its really helpful

Answer (score 0):

- I think when you use it in the bean class of spring boot, it is equivalent to calling spring to help you inject a bean object named `authUrl` and its type is `java.lang.String`. Obviously, you did not define a bean object with `authUrl`, so an error was reported.
- If you really need to use `@AllArgsConstructor` to assign values to class members, I suggest you use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`  instead of it, and at the same time, use final modification for the member variables that need to be constructed. Others, such as `authUrl` in your example, do not need to use final modify.
- Hope that will helps you, good luck

Comment: thanks i will look up the difference between allargsconstructor and requiredargsconstructor